# Merging sublists if values of subsequent list match

Tags: python, list

I have two input irregular list of lists. One contains z-coordinates of certain nodes and the other the corresponding id of the node as follows:

```
z   = [[0,0,0],[2,2,2],[0,0],[3],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[0,0]] #z_coordinates per node
ids = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[4,5],[9],[20,21],[41,42],[15,16],[33,34]] #id per node
```

What I'm trying to do is to merge the rows of z, when the values are equal and return the corresponding (merged) ids, so the desired output would be:

```
z_merged   = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4,4,4,4,4]]
ids_merged = [[1,2,3,4,5,33,34],[11,12,13],[9],[20,21,15,16,41,42]]
```

What I have tried so far is to sort the list, and check if the first value of the previous sublist corresponds with the first value of the current sublist. This returns the correct indices:

```
z = sorted(z)
index = []
for i in range(1, len(z)):
    if z[i-1][0] == z[i][0]:
        index.append(i-1)
        index.append(i)
        
index = np.unique(index)
index
```

So I know now that of the sorted z list, I need to merge sublists 0,1,2 and 5,6,7. However I am stuck to figure out how to actually merge them. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your `z` and `ids` - it does not make sense, if they are not `matrix'.  Please confirm. Because you also motioned they are `sublists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this by using defaultdicts for the merge. Explanation of steps -

1. First is to get the key, value from the zip of z and ids. So for the first, key is 0 and value is [1,2,3]
2. Initialize a default dict
3. For a given key, append each of the elements in list v to the default dict. print this to get more details!
4. My ids merged are simply the values of this dict!
5. The merged z is a bit complex. You will have to regenerate the z by using the default dict key and repeating it to the length of each element in ids_merged.

```
from collections import defaultdict

z   = [0,0,0],[2,2,2],[0,0],[3],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[0,0]
ids = [1,2,3],[11,12,13],[4,5],[9],[20,21],[41,42],[15,16],[33,34]

dicts = [(j[0],i) for i,j in zip(ids, z)]

d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in dicts:
    for j in v:
        d[k].append(j)
      
ids_merged = list(d.values())

z_merged = [[list(d.keys())[i]]*len(j) for i,j in enumerate(ids_merged)]

print(z_merged)
print(ids_merged)
```

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 33, 34], [11, 12, 13], [9], [20, 21, 41, 42, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: I suspected that either itertools or collections would have the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: yea. merging problems? collections ftw, always.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option without using `collections`:

```
z   = [[0,0,0],[2,2,2],[0,0],[3],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[0,0]]
ids = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[4,5],[9],[20,21],[41,42],[15,16],[33,34]]

z = [item for sublist in z for item in sublist]
ids = [item for sublist in ids for item in sublist]

dictionary = {}

for item_index, item in enumerate(z):
    if item in dictionary:
        dictionary[item].append(ids[item_index])
    else:
        dictionary[item] = [ids[item_index]]

merged_z = []
merged_ids = []

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    merged_z.append([key] * len(value))
    merged_ids.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without any imports would be

```
z   = [0,0,0],[2,2,2],[0,0],[3],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[0,0]
ids = [1,2,3],[11,12,13],[4,5],[9],[20,21],[41,42],[15,16],[33,34]

z_flat = [item for sublist in z for item in sublist]
ids_flat = [item for sublist in ids for item in sublist]

z_merged = []
ids_merged = []
for i in range(max(z_flat)+1):
    z_add = []
    ids_add = []
    for j in range(len(z_flat)):
        if z_flat[j] == i:
            z_add.append(z_flat[j])
            ids_add.append(ids_flat[j])
    if z_add:
        z_merged.append(z_add)
        ids_merged.append(ids_add)
```

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2], [3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 33, 34], [11, 12, 13], [9], [20, 21, 41, 42, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a dictionary with your "z" coordinates as key, and add all ids corresponding to that coordinate, then iterate your dictionary to create `z_merged` and `ids_merged`.

```py
z   = [[0,0,0],[2,2,2],[0,0],[3],[4,4],[4,4],[4,4],[0,0]]
ids = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[4,5],[9],[20,21],[41,42],[15,16],[33,34]]

d = {}
for q, w in zip(z, ids):
    d.setdefault(str(q[0]), []).extend(w)

z_merged = []
ids_merged = []
for k, v in d.items():
    z_merged.append([int(k)] * len(v))
    ids_merged.append(v)
```